# Merging two rows together in a table so that no cells are visible

Tags: html, css

```css
table {
  border-spacing:0 10px;
  border-collapse:separate; 
}

td {
  padding:2px 10px;
  border-top:1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}

td.gray {
  background:#ddd
}

td:last-child {
  border-right:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="gray"> Module description </td>

 </tr>
 <tr rowspan = "2">
 <td> This module aims to provide a comprehensive knowledge and experience of the relational database model and 
 its effective design, administration and implementation in order to to support data driven applications.</td>

</table>
```

Below are the images of what I want my table to look like and what I have at the moment. I cant get the table rows to merge and get rid of the division between the first and second row.

This is what I want the table to look like:
[image: This is what I want the table to look like]

This is what I have so far:
[image: This is what I have so far.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the padding and removing the border-spacing will do the trick:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

td.gray {
  background:#ddd
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="gray"> Module description </td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> This module aims to provide a comprehensive knowledge and experience of the relational database model and 
 its effective design, administration and implementation in order to to support data driven applications.</td>

</table>
```

A little background: with `border-collapse` (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)) you define whether cell borders are separate (like in your question) or collapsed. `Rowspan` only works for expanding a cell vertically across more than one row (tr) and hence did not do anything here.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple columns and want to merge the row for one of those columns you can use the rowspan. As you have only one column above, you can't use this here.

I have modified few css below.

```css
table {
  border-collapse:separate; 
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0;
}

td {
  padding:2px 10px;
}

td.gray {
  background:#ddd
}

td:last-child {
  border-top:0 solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="gray"> Module description </td>
       
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> This module aims to provide a comprehensive knowledge and experience of the relational database model and 
 its effective design, administration and implementation in order to to support data driven applications.</td>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```css
table {
  border-spacing:0 10px;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
  padding:2px 10px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
td.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="gray"> Module description </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This module aims to provide a comprehensive knowledge and experience of the relational database model and 
its effective design, administration and implementation in order to to support data driven applications.Bla Bla Bla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You had some errors in your html syntax.